# How to rename large amounts of .asc files at once? with MS Office or Matlab

Tags: matlab, ms-office, ascii, file-rename, batch-rename

Here's the scenario: I've got this grid builder that runs large amounts of data at once, usually requiring about 10 hours per completion. It spat at all of my latest .asc files as

```
    oak_sabppt_2010_01_01.asc
    oak_sabppt_2010_01_02.asc
    oak_sabppt_2010_01_03.asc
```

etc
etc
etc... when they should just be titled:

```
    ppt_2010_01_01.asc
    ppt_2010_01_02.asc
    ppt_2010_01_02.asc
```

etc
etc
etc...

Seeing as how I've got about a decade worth of these files that fail to match the titles of previous decades, I'd like to change all of the names by taking off the 'oak_sab' prefix it just recently tagged on.

The problem that needs solved: What are some suggestions on the most expedient and efficient route to rename batches of .asc files all at once? 
The only programs I have as tools at my disposal are microsoft office and matlab, so suggestions within those parameters would be most valued!

Thanks,
-J

Comment: Why MATLAB (!) or Office? You can do it with Total Commander (Multi-Rename Tool) in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows, you can use the Windows command prompt or PowerShell for this. For example, to remove the 'oak_sab' from all files in the current directory, try the following line in PowerShell:

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “oak_sab“,”” }
```

More info is here: http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed. Thanks DMR!